# Enlarge font in a book (ibooks, iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, books

I purchased a book through iBooks that appears to be in a pdf format. The font is so tiny that it's hard to read even with a max zoom. What can I do do enlarge the font even more? I tried importing to the Acrobat app to see if it's different there, but it won't import. 
Book in question: https://books.apple.com/us/book/the-paleo-approach/id797715067

Comment: It probably has DRM so you can't read it in another app.  If you can't read it, you can try to ask for a refund.   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204084

Comment: It is just readable for me when spread out over a 21 inch iMac.